# Cardinality of definable sets of reals

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory

Throughout this question we assume ZFC.

If CH holds, then the following is obvious:

> (S) Every definable infinite subset of $\mathbb R$ has size either $\aleph_0$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$.

(It's true because *every* subset of reals satisfies this, in particular so does every definable)

Recently my friend has asked me whether the same is true if we assume CH fails. My answer was that this is independent of ZFC, because I'm fairly sure that results about pointwise definable models will gives us such model of ZFC + not CH (correct me if I'm wrong!) in which a set of reals of size $\aleph_1$ is definable, and I can recall seeing a result that (S) can hold, possibly under some large cardinal assumption. However, I failed to find a reference for that.

Hence my question is for a reference of the following result (if my memory isn't failing me and it's actually true):

> It is consistent (relatively to large cardinals) that CH fails and (S) holds.

I also wanted to ask if this is true if CH fails badly:

> Is it consistent for every cardinal $\kappa$ that (S) holds and $2^{\aleph_0}>\kappa$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VictoriaGitman That's not a problem, as I hope it's clarified now :)

Comment: Two possible models: (i) Start with GCH and force with finite partial functions from $\kappa$ to $\omega_1$ for a regular $\kappa \geq \omega_3$. (ii) Levy collapse an inaccessible $\kappa$ to $\omega_1$ (Solovay's model) and then add $\kappa^{+}$ Cohen reals. (i) works for ordinal definable sets of reals and (ii) also allows a real parameter.

Comment: I don't have a published reference for this. These examples were suggested to me by Kunen and Arnie Miller when I was a grad student.

Comment: Would I sound too naive if I ask what you exactly mean by "definable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$"? Sometimes people use that phrase for projective sets of reals, which have the perfect set property under suitable large cardinal assumptions.

Comment: @Burak Given a model $M$ of $ZFC$, I call set $S$ in that model definable if there is a formula $\phi(x)$ without parameters such that $\phi(x)\Leftrightarrow x\in S$.

Comment: @Wojowu: Thanks for the clarification. Since you mentioned pointwise definable models, I was thinking that you probably mean "definable" in the model theoretic sense but wanted to double check anyway.

Comment: It's okay if definable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ means projective sets, because under $AD$ in $L(\mathbb{R})$, projective sets have the perfect set property, yet CH, or at least a definable version of it, fails very badly, because $\delta^1_3=\aleph_{\omega+1}$. (read $\delta^1_3$ with a tilde under it, i.e not the lightface version).

Comment: @Carlo: That depends on how you formulate CH, though. :-)

Comment: By definable, do you mean "in $\mathsf{HOD}$"? If so, the answer is yes, this is consistent. Note that the failure of $\mathsf{CH}$ adds nothing, since you can violate $\mathsf{CH}$ with homogeneous forcing.

Comment: The chapter by Koellner and Woodin discusses definable determinacy to some length. We also know the consistency of stronger versions (for instance, determinacy of all games of length $\omega_1$ definable from ordinals and real parameters).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Based on the exchange between Wojowu and Burak, I think "definable" means "definable in $V$ by a first-order formula without parameters." So, incomparable with HOD, in principle.

Comment: @NoahSchweber "Definable in $V$ by a first order formula" gives us that the set is in $\mathsf{HOD}$ by reflection.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Derp, of course, you're right.

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding something in this discussion but isn't the set of non constructible reals in a Cohen real extension of $L$ a definable set outside HOD?

Comment: Final comment: I also think that a permutation argument should imply that the model (i) in my first comment does satisfy (S).

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT: This isn't really an answer - see Andres' comment - but you might find it interesting, and it is too long for a comment.*

Your second question is vague, but has an affirmative answer in the following sense:

> Let $V\models ZFC+V=L$, and let $\kappa$ be a cardinal in $V$. Then there is a forcing extension $V[G]$ of $V$ in which $2^{\aleph_0}>\kappa$ but there is a definable set of reals of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Proof: Add $\kappa^+$-many Cohen reals; this bumps the continuum up to $\kappa^+$. Meanwhile, it does not collapse $\aleph_1$, so the set $V\cap\mathbb{R}$ of ground reals is still of size $\aleph_1$. And $V\cap\mathbb{R}=(\mathbb{R}^L)^V=(\mathbb{R}^L)^{V[G]}$, so is definable in $V[G]$ without parameters.

---

The first question seems harder. Any countable model of ZFC has a class forcing extension which is pointwise definable, but this class forcing extension doesn't seem to preserve large cardinal properties. Meanwhile, "big enough" large cardinals kill off all the obvious ways to try to define sets of reals of intermediate cardinality.

Comment: This is not really addressing the question as given. The background theory here should be $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{LC}$ rather than just $\mathsf{ZFC}$, for $\mathsf{LC}$ a (significant) large cardinal assumption.  That is, we want large cardinals in our universe, and still determinacy of definable games. This rules out models obtained by forcing over $L$ or thin inner models.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo That's true, but I wasn't sure if the OP was aware of constructions like this, so I thought it worth pointing out. I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Note that you can do the same trick as long as you have nicely absolute core models, so I think this style of argument is compatible with a decent amount of large cardinal structure. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: i dont know what Andres Caicedo's objection is but you produced a model of not(S) plus stuff while the op asked if there were models of (s) plus stuff.